# Parsing Complex JSON file with JQ Issue

Tags: json, bash, csv, jq

I have big JSON file with 100000 results. I know how to do basic parsing with `'JQ'`.

## virus.json

```
{
  "detected": true,
  "result": "Trojan.Win32.Generic!BT",
  "update": "20170115",
  "version": "1.5.0.42"
}
{
  "detected": true,
  "result": "FileCryptor.NJX",
  "update": "20170115",
  "version": "16.0.0.4749"
}
{
  "detected": true,
  "result": "Generic.Ransom.Purge.DC87C66E",
  "update": "20170115",
  "version": "1.0.1.9"
}
```

But on this JSON file , I would like to get the fields such as "detected" and "result" in a `CSV` format. I know how to get it individually using JQ.

I tried ,

## 1

```
$ jq -r ".detected" virus.json 

true
true
true
```

## 2

```
 $ jq -r ".result" dum_1.json 

    Trojan.Win32.Generic!BT
    FileCryptor.NJX
    Generic.Ransom.Purge.DC87C66E
```

## 3

```
jq -r ".detected,.result" dum_1.json 
true
Trojan.Win32.Generic!BT
true
FileCryptor.NJX
true
Generic.Ransom.Purge.DC87C66E
```

Instead of #3 , I would like the output to be as

## Output

```
true , Trojan.Win32.Generic!BT
true , FileCryptor.NJX
true , Generic.Ransom.Purge.DC87C66E
```

Any suggestion on how to get the results ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@csv will convert from a flat array to CSV, so this should get you started:

```
jq -r '[.detected, .result] | @csv'
```

Given your sample input, this will produce:

```
true,"Trojan.Win32.Generic!BT"
true,"FileCryptor.NJX"
true,"Generic.Ransom.Purge.DC87C66E"
```

If you want the quotation marks removed, then consider:

```
jq -r '"\(.detected), \(.result)"'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sed`:

```
jq -r ".detected,.result" dum_1.json | sed 'N;s/\n/ , /'
true , Trojan.Win32.Generic!BT
true , FileCryptor.NJX
true , Generic.Ransom.Purge.DC87C66E
```

The `sed` `N` command read the next line, joining the 2 lines together.

The `s` command is replacing the newline `\n` with the wanted pattern `,`.

Answer (score 1):

```
jq -r ".detected,.result" dum_1.json |awk -v OFS=, 'NR%2{x=$0;next} {print x OFS $0}'
true,Trojan.Win32.Generic!BT
true,FileCryptor.NJX
true,Generic.Ransom.Purge.DC87C66E
```